# Show div of different page when hovering on element in index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently started to learn with Javascript language and I already faced trouble. What I want to do is to with mouse hover show div content of another page (which is in same domain but different folder). I managed to get two scripts. First script fits to show the div but it shows only if different div is in the same page. Here are two parts of it (first is Javascript and second part is html):

http://pastebin.com/sHbh7jhn

```
<a onmouseover="ShowContent('ContentName'); return true;"
onmouseout="HideContent('ContentName'); return true;"
href="javascript:ShowContent('ContentName')">
<img style="float:right; src="somesource.png"/>
</a>

<div id="ContentName" style="display:none;">
Content goes here.
</div>
```

I also saw this (second) totally different code works too and even showing of different page's div. The problem with this code is that shows on page load, instantly, without hovering on anything, etc.

```
jQuery(function($){
$('#mydiv').load('ContentName');
});
```

I searched in here for answers but I didn't find the answer neither in here or in anywhere else. How I should edit the code (either first one or second) so that on mouse hover (on div) I could see a div of other page (how to combine these two codes, if possible)?

Since I'm newbie, something might be missing.

Comment: To be more clear, what is the server-side technology? I mean php/asp.net,...?

Comment: @genichm Why does it matter?

Comment: If it is asp.net mvc I can suggest you several ways to do it, if not than it can be done by ajax request and some manipulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. load url content to some hidden div

   ```
   jQuery(function ($) {
       $('#hidden_div_id').load("http://...");
   });
   ```
2. Add hover event to your div

   ```
   $("#mydiv").mouseover(function () {
      document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loaded div id").innerHTML;
   });
   ```

inside of mouseover event write your function that selects some particular div content and inserts it into your div. It may be the solution.

But the best solution is to create particular div that will include only required data and to include it on mouse over.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [jQuery.load() API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

In short you could do

> $( "#myDiv" ).load( "/mypath/some.html #someDivId" );

However the clean way to deal with this is to keep the contents of #someFicId in a separate fragment file and make sure this has strictly HTML/CSS

> $( "#myDiv" ).load( "/mypath/someFragment.frag.html" );

Comment: That's not bad idea. But perhaps you know how to combine these two codes so I can see only part of that other file (1 div)?

Comment: I would recommend the second approach but keep smaller shared DIVs in separate individual files so that you can make them more reusable. But if your application is big and beginning to grow you may want to use some frameworks like angularJS/ember. In angularJS this is a piece of cake and would recommend if you are start from scratch as it will change the fundamental programming model.