# Get data from ajax response

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to get data from ajax script. I mean I have a web-site which contains some comments. I want to get them. Ajax script downloads them using post-request. I tried do this :

> curl -d "data" -H "Accept: application/xml"  POST url

But this request returns only main page of that site. I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can find answer here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132952/show-div-of-different-page-when-hovering-on-element-in-index-page/27133791#27133791)

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert in every comment box a name attribute like

```
name="user"
```

then,in your php page,insert the global variable

$_POST["user"]

after POST you must insert the name of the comment box you inserted.
to show the comment or to save the comment try to save the value in a variable like this

```
value=$_POST["user"]
```

then make what you want of this variable.You can save this variable in a txt file too.